# Program that does wc command in unix. Wrong word count

Tags: c, unix

I having a problem with the output of the word count.  Sometimes it's counting a space as a word.

```
n = read(inFile,buffer,512);
    int i;  
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
     if(buffer[i] == '\n') {
       l++;
       if(buffer[i-1] != '\n' || buffer[i-1] == EOF ){ 
         if(buffer[i-1] != ' '){
            w++;
        }    
       }//end if
     }//end if
     if(buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\t'){
       w++;//get the word
     }//end if

    b++;//get the byte
  }//end for

 printf(" %d %d %d %s \n" ,l,w,b,argv[1]);   

 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide test data and the expected/observed outputs.

Comment: When`i==0` this `if(buffer[i-1] != '\n' || buffer[i-1] == EOF )` will cause Undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suspect that lines like this `if(buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\t') { w++; }` are treating instances of double-space as extra words.

Comment: You are just reading 512 bytes once, are you reading the complete file ?

Comment: You have some undefined behavior going on for input files which have a `\n` as the first byte in the file. In that case, your code is attempting to access `buffer[-1]`. Also, I'm not clear on how you expect to ever have an `EOF` in your buffer, since the `read` function is not going to write an `EOF` into your buffer, and even if it did, you're not going to iterate beyond that point.

Comment: Additionally, it's much better and clearer to use `isspace()` instead of testing particular character values.  As it is, you're not consistent as to whether a tab is counted as a space or not.

Comment: Instead of looking at positions near the current one in the buffer, you could structure this better by keeping a flag tracking whether you are currently scanning a word or not, and incrementing your word count (only) when the flag flips from false to true.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of detecting EOF with a buffer returned by `read` is wrong. There is no EOF character in the buffer. The EOF must be detected by looking at read's return value.

From `man 2 read`

> RETURN VALUES
>
> ```
>  If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon
>  reading end-of-file, zero is returned.  Otherwise, a -1 is returned and
>  the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.
> ```